# plot graph using plotly.ts in ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, plotly, plotly.js

I'm trying to plot a graph in an ionic 3 project using plotly.js however I'm having trouble creating a simple plot. I did the following for my setup:

```
npm install --save plotly.js
npm install --save @types/plotly.js
```

I then included the following in my ionic component:

```
import * as Plotly from 'plotly.js'; 

drawChart() {
  const data = [{
    x: ['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
    y: [20, 14, 23],
    type: 'bar'
  }];
  Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
}
```

when  I now run

```
tsc
```

I get the following error:

```
Argument of type '{ x: string[]; y: number[]; type: string; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<ScatterData>[]'.
Type '{ x: string[]; y: number[]; type: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<ScatterData>'.
Types of property 'type' are incompatible. Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"bar" | "pointcloud" | "scatter" | "scattergl" | "scatter3d" | "surface"'.
```

Did I miss anything? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Try uninstalling the `types` and see if it renders?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, this didn't get the job done though, unfortunately I still get the same error